# Django create app error

Tags: python, django

I want to create the app in django 1.8.12

and I type `python manage.py startapp fb_weatherbot

and the traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'fb_weatherbot'
```

What part I missed?

I have added the app in INSTALLED_APPS in the settings.py

thank you.

Comment: the name of your app is "myapp" and not "fb_weatherbot". Edit your settings with the right app name

Comment: You are importing `fb_weatherbot` into your application. You need to put this module (fb_weatherbot) where your myapp is. Error it self saying everything. Check you code you are importing somewhere `fb_weatherbot` this. and this is not available.

Comment: @Abhishek @webDev: 'myapp' is my edit ignore.I actually excetute `python manage.py startapp fb_weatherbot`,and then the traceback appear immediately.Additionally,I do nothing.thx reply

Comment: Don't add fb_weatherbot to INSTALLED_APPS before create it.

Answer (score 6):

Add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` after running startapp, not before.

**Explanation:** running `manage.py` imports `settings.py`, so it tries to find `fb_weatherbot` app which doesn't exist (yet).

**Example** (error output truncated):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    …
    'fb_weatherbot'
]

$ ./manage.py startapp fb_weatherbot
Traceback (most recent call last):
…
ImportError: No module named 'fb_weatherbot'
```

---

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    …
    # 'fb_weatherbot'
]

$ ./manage.py startapp fb_weatherbot
$ # outputs nothing, app is created
```

Uncomment it again after running startapp, of course.